# Updating a (Windows 10 Home) Windows To Go installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-to-go

I have a Windows to Go (W2G) Windows 10 Home installation. The Anniversary Update was released a few days ago. However, I cannot install it because "You can't install Windows on a USB flash drive using Setup."

The fix that I've found everywhere is to change the Registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PortableOperatingSystem` from `0` to `1`.

However, a W2G installation *IS* a PortableOperatingSystem by definition. Is it safe to just change the key in this case? Do I have some other alternative (that is not reinstalling from scratch, of course) to update this system?

Comment: Windows Update can't install the update because it shows that error :)

Answer (score 1):

It did updating a WindowsToGo Pro from earlier R1 143xx Builds several times until the 14393 after changing the `PortableOperatingSystem` value. For me it worked fine without any issues. Before doing it, use a [backup tool](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) to create a full image of the Windows To Go.